# Install pfksh on OpenSolaris

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

I have an OpenSolaris system and some korn shell scripts that have a #!/bin/pfksh at the top. However, I don't have pfksh in either /bin/ or /usr/bin directories.

How should I go about installing pfksh on my system? When I tried to copy the file, I get a "Invalid argument" error message. I couldn't find the exact name of the package in OpenSolaris to install pfksh.

pkg install pfksh
pkg install SUNWpfksh

don't work.

I tried copying the pfksh file from another machine, but it gives me

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](http://osdir.com/ml/os.solaris.opensolaris.pkg.general/2008-06/msg00879.html) you should download the [ksh93](http://www.opensolaris.org/os/project/ksh93-integration/downloads/2008-06-24/) package, once you have it you will need to create a [hardlink](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/173/create-a-hard-link-in-unix/) for pfksh

Answer (score 1):

pfksh is a Solaris profile shell (see manual pages for pfexe(1) and rbac(5) for more information) and it is a link to /usr/bin/sh which is delivered in the SUNWcs package, but on OpenSolaris where it seems to have been forgotten.

If you just do the following, it will work

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s ksh pfksh
```